# MUnicycling tips: Which tricks to practice to improve mountain unicycling performance

Tags: mountain-bike, skills, unicycle

I recently bought a unicycle with the purpose of riding mountain trails. I live in Patagonia where there are plenty of nice mountain trails and I used to do a lot of mountain biking there, but temporally (next 4 months) I am living in a very flat city with no mountains.
I can unicycle well in the city on paved flat surfaces, but I would like to get the skills needed to Municycle when back home. The best would be to practice in irregular trails, but even parks around here have all trails paved.
So far, from other forums I got these tips I can practice here:

- Learn bunny hoping to be able to go over bigger obstacles.
- Learn to ride with one pedal to be prepared in case one of your foot looses the pedal (seems to be frequent...).

And that's it. I haven't found any unicycling tutorials focused on mountain unicycling.
I am looking for more tips from experienced riders.

1. What would be the most useful skill needed for mountain unicycling (that could be practised in flat land)?
2. What is the best riding position? In videos I see most people riding with one hand in the saddle. which one is best (for a right-handed)?

Comment: Trying unicycling is still on my to do list, but my intuition says controlled falls and sudden, sharp turns. Although you may have gone through plenty of those already on a unicycle...

Answer (score 3):

The most important skill would be just getting comfortable on tree unicyle. Ride daily, practice bunny hops. I am sure that there are pavements, try hopping off them and up them or you can build up to this by only jumping up and down smaller things. Then try jumping large gaps. Try jumping a large gap off the pavement and up it. Find any irregular paths. In my country-south africa there are millions of potholes.

The best riding position would be using which ever hand is more comfortable and would feel that you have a stronger control over the unicyle. For example which hand would you put on the unicyle to jump with it. You don't really need two hands on the seat. Only if u have a unicyle with brakes or you want to go fast or their is an extremely bumpy section coming up, only then would I us eboth hand as their are many pros with using one hand such as better balance and you can cushion a fall.

Now this is only for me so you try what feels better and in conclusion to this question  just do what you feel right. Use both hands if u need more control and you only one hand when you feel you got this.

The time u got this message would probably mean u back to the mountains. Just practice the trails. Get experience. You can do it.